# Force Pandas to keep multiple columns with the same name

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm building a program that collects data and adds it to an ongoing excel sheet weekly (read_excel() and concat() with the new data). The issue I'm having is that I need the columns to have the same name for presentation (it doesn't look great with x.1, x.2, ...).

I only need this on the final output. Is there any way to accomplish this? Would it be too time consuming to modify pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a list of custom headers that will be read into excel

```
newColNames = ['x','x','x'.....]

df.to_excel(path,header=newColNames)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add spaces to the end of the column name.  It will appear the same in a Excel, but pandas can distinguish the difference.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], columns=['x','x ','x  '])

df
   x  x   x
0  1   2    3
1  4   5    6
2  7   8    9
```